# MCP4728 on RP4 with Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, dac

I am trying to use MCP4728 DAC with RP4.
I can’t get it to work.
Connection map:
RP4 1 (3.3V) to 1 at 4728.
RP4 6 (GND) to 10 at 4728.
RP4 3 (SDA) to 3 at 4728.
RP4 5 (SCL) to 2 at 4728.
GND to 4 at 4728.

Tried using this code:

```
import board
import busio
import adafruit_mcp4728

i2c = busio.I2C(board.SCL, board.SDA)
mcp4728 =  adafruit_mcp4728.MCP4728(i2c)
```

with an error: `No I2C device at address: 0x60`

Tried using this code:

```
from smbus import SMBus 
bus = SMBus(1) #indicates /dev/i2c-1
addr = 0x60
bus.write_byte(addr, 0x50)
```

with an error: `[Errno 121] Remote I/O error`

Any ideas ?
Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure the MCP4728 wasn't reprogrammed to use a different address (0x61-0x67)?

Comment: Thank you for that, doubled checked, and yes.
it is at a different address.
all is working now :)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
# write to MCP4728
#for the first channel
    command = 0x58 
    addr = 0x61 #bus address
    bus = SMBus(1) #indicates /dev/i2c-1
    bus.write_i2c_block_data(addr,command,[value_msb,value_lsb])
```